# Обновление базы данных через sql update c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Я подключаю базу данных к winForms и вывожу через dataGridView, после чего когда изменил некоторые ячейки (мне нужно именно изменить, не добавить, и изменения могут быть не в одной строчке а в множестве сразу же), через dataset пытаюсь обновить базу данных, но она не обновляется. Я просто не знаю почему, код вроде правильный, про бывал уже по всякому. Вот код

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Журнал_СШ
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        DataSet dataSet;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        string server = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Журнал;Integrated Security=True";
        string sql, table;

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        // кнопка сохранения
        private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          //  try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(server))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        for (int l = 0; l < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; l++)
                            for (int t = 0; t < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; t++)
                                dataSet.Tables["Class"].Rows[l][t] = dataGridView1.Rows[l].Cells[t].Value;
                        for (int l = 0; l < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; l++)
                            for (int t = 1; t < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; t++)
                            {
                                if (t + 3 < dataSet.Tables["Class"].Columns.Count)
                                {
                                    command.CommandText = "UPDATE [" + table + "] SET Дата" + t + " = @dannie WHERE id = @id";
                                    command.Parameters.Add("@dannie", SqlDbType.Int);
                                    command.Parameters["@dannie"].Value = dataSet.Tables["Class"].Rows[l][t + 2];
                                    command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
                                    command.Parameters["@id"].Value = dataSet.Tables["Class"].Rows[l][0];
                                    adapter.UpdateCommand = command;
                                    adapter.Update(dataSet.Tables["Class"]);
                                }
                            }
                        connection.Close();
                    } 
                }
            }
         /*   catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }*/
        }

        private void Load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                table = textBox1.Text;
                sql = "SELECT * FROM [";
                dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                sql += table + "]";
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(server))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);

                    dataSet = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Class");
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["Class"];

                    dataGridView1.Columns["id"].ReadOnly = true;
                    dataGridView1.Columns["id"].Visible = false;
                    dataGridView1.Columns["Группа"].ReadOnly = true;
                    dataGridView1.Columns["Группа"].Visible = false;
                    dataGridView1.Columns["Имя"].ReadOnly = true;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код таблицы:

```
[id]     INT        NOT NULL,
    [Группа] NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Имя]    NCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [Дата1]  INT        NULL,
    [Дата2]  INT        NULL,
    [Дата3]  INT        NULL,
    [Дата4]  INT        NULL,
    [Дата5]  INT        NULL,
    [Дата6]  INT        NULL,
    [Дата7]  INT        NULL,
    [Дата8]  INT        NULL
```

Comment: Код работает, не работает кнопка Save. И да там есть try и catch, но они добавлены в комментарии, поэтому они не важны никак. Мне нужна помощь с SQL кодом и что там не так, почему он не работает

Comment: Что значит `не работает кнопка Save`? Как это проявляется? Выбрасывается `Exception` или просто данные не обновляются в базе данных?

Comment: Не обновляются данные в бд, я не понимаю почему, пытался писать по разному, но я уже устал искать решения, которые не работают

Comment: А можете прикрепить к вопросу имена и типы столбцов в таблице `Class`?

Comment: Вам не надо бегать в цикле по DGV, у вас же есть DataSet, таблица из которого привязана в качестве источника к DGV. Все новые и измененные значения отслеживаются автоматом в этом DataSet, вам достаточно сделать у адаптера Update(), и всё.

Comment: Когда я выполняю `Update()` для `adapter` он мне выдавал ошибку `System.InvalidOperationException: "Для обновления требуется действительный UpdateCommand при передаче коллекции DataRow с измененными строками."` @Bulson